# which windows 10 edition for running docker containers?

Tags: windows, docker

it says that prereqisite is windows 10 pro or enterprise edition because of hyper-v but ia that for running windows containers only or is pro/enterprise edition needed for running linux containers also?

Comment: i am running it from windows 10 familly i got hyper-v x64 I7 .

Comment: Both. If you don't want that you need to use Docker toolbox which uses virtualbox

Comment: thanks for your input! is there any negative with using Docker toolbox instead? (having on mind i need linux containers only)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to a Windows 10 version with Hyper-V, you can use the older Docker Toolbox product which relies on VirtualBox: https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox

Comment: great! is there any negative going with that option haing on mind i need linux containers only? (you can add answer to that in your answer so i can accept it. thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

As @friism pointed out w/o HyperV you have to use the old Docker toolbox option. This is due to the fact that the docker daemon does not run on Windows natively. Instead it started a small Linux machine (on windows using hyperV); inside this linux machine is where all the docker and tools are executed. The desktop client is simply a nice UI to send the commands to the virtualized linux machine.